# LLVM compilation not working with Haskell on Yosemite

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc

I'm trying to use llvm with haskell and I'm getting the error "illegal hardware instruction"

Details:

I'm compiling a simple hello world program just to test it out:

Code:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

GHC version 7.10.1, llvm version 3.4.2 (older version because haskell doesn't work at all with 3.6.1).

Command to compile: `ghc -O2 --make firstProgram.hs -fllvm -fforce-recomp`

Exact error with command `./firstProgram`

`[1]    23665 illegal hardware instruction  ./firstProgram`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand how you didn't get a compile-time error (maybe your program is too trivial?) but GHC 7.10.* specifically needs LLVM 3.5.*, not an earlier or later version.

Comment: Hi. I tried that and it still does not work. Tested it out on a basic factorial function and I get the same error.